# Auto scrolling PDF reader?

Tags: pdf

Is there any PDF reader that does auto scrolling? I have some sheet music in PDF that I want to be able to scroll through

Answer (score 1):

[ezPDF Reader Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader&hl=en) has a feature `Page Auto Flipping` which auto-scroll screen every provided second.

Answer (score 1):

[Pro PDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobnix.pro.pdf.reader&hl=en) has auto scrolling feature

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried MobileSheets? I use it a lot for music scores